# context set data to strings and pass on javascript webview, work only with "numbers"

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, webview

I try to pass data from a database to webview form, for now work but if i add only numbers from database e.g. code is 123 and region is 567, if code is 123-4 and region is France nothing show to webview html... Any help please I want numbers and words on webview...???

MainActivity.java

```
void setCodeAndRegion(final String code, final String region) {
    webview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webview.evaluateJavascript("javascript:setCodeAndRegion(" + code + "," + region + ");", null);
        }
    });
}
```

popupdialog.java

```
listRegion.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final String region = (String) listRegion.getItemAtPosition(position);
            SQLiteDatabase database = context.pdfDatabaseManager.getReadableDatabase();
            final Cursor c = database.rawQuery("Select * From " + PDFDatabaseManager.DATABASE_REGION_TABLE + " WHERE "+ PDFDatabaseManager.KEY_REGION +"='"+region+"'", null);
            String code = "";
            while (c.moveToNext())
                code = c.getString(1);

            c.close();
            context.setCodeAndRegion(code,region);
            a.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

.html

```
 var setCodeAndRegion = function(code, region){
          document.getElementById('test1').value = code;
          document.getElementById('test2').value = region;
          alert (region);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be the values you're passing as arguments in the function `setCodeAndRegion`.
Since they are **Strings** (at least for the region) you need **quotation marks** ( **"** or **'** ).

```
void setCodeAndRegion(final String code, final String region) {
    webview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            webview.evaluateJavascript("javascript:setCodeAndRegion('" + code + "', '" + region + "');", null);
        }
    });
}
```

This is ok:

```
"javascript:setCodeAndRegion('" + code + "', '" + region + "');"
```

This will not be interpreted well by javascript:

```
"javascript:setCodeAndRegion("+ code + ", " + region + " );"
```

Simply because javascript will not be able to recognize it as a value. It would become something like this:

```
setCodeAndRegion(123-5, England );
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer friend now this work!!! :))